# How to get size of data in Infinispan cache, alternate for calculateInMemorySize of ehcache?

Tags: java, ehcache, infinispan

I am migrating from ehcache to infinispan.
In ehcache we have

```
net.sf.ehcache.Cache.calculateInMemorySize()
```

to calculate in memory size.

How to calculate in memory size in infinispan?

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't be so easy in Infinispan. To calculate memory size effectively you need every objects in the cache to be serialized into a byte array (store as binary configuration) and probably for each entry's key and value calculate size in bytes. For example using ByteArrayOutputStream. There is a possibility of creation DistributedExecution task for this which takes all cache entries and do some operations on top of them (here, calculating its keys and values sizes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomas is right, there's no currently no way to calculate size of data in memory. We do however provide users with some guidelines on [the memory overhead that Infinispan incurs](http://infinispan.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/infinispan-memory-overhead.html), which helps users plan their memory requirements. Calculating the size of data in-memory is not trivial to achieve and requires a lot of subtle details to be taken into account (type of JVM, arquitecture...etc).